# How to add Custom Action in Visual Studio Setup Project to Install MySql

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2010, installation, custom-action

I have successfully created a setup for my application using Visual Studio Setup project.Now as per my need i have to link Mysql to install before installation of the Setup project created by me.I tried it with custom action but i am not able to get it correctly.

I want my setup project should direct to the Mysql and later it should start the installation as per the Mysql installer and one Mysql installation is over it should resume my Installer setup.

Please help me .
Thanks in advance.